# Weird iptables patterns of closed ports

Tags: networking, security, iptables

Scratching my head over this one...I'm using Shields Up while proxied into a server I just setup with Rackspace. Here's my iptables config:

```
*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow SSH connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

#  Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

I've saved this into a config file and loaded it up using iptables-restore. Here's what my port scan is looking like:

[image]

What could possibly cause this pattern of closed ports?

EDIT: output of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Please include the output of `iptables -L`.
 
I'm not familiar with your ShieldsUp tool or how it does its testing, so I'll be making assumptions.  Can you include the text summary?  Note also that 443 is showing closed for the remote utility, even though you're supposedly listening.

Comment: Your iptables is artistic!

Comment: Just added the iptables -L output...here's the tool I'm using: https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2 Port 443 doesn't have anything listening on it at the moment.

Comment: Anyway, `REJECT` is reserved for very specific cases. Using `REJECT` implies that your server will send a reject response to the peer that is trying to connect, and it is really stupid to do if its a DDOS attack. In case of doubt, always use `DROP` instead of `REJECT`.

Comment: @Havenard "REJECT" is reserved for this very specific case: a firewall's negative response. There is nothing stupid to it and there is no sane way to drive a DDoS attack out of it as the response size of the ICMP packet is around 100 Bytes - not exactly what a magnification attack would need to succeed.

Comment: @syneticon-dj that will depend. On a professional server, upload bandwidth is generally prioritized, but a home server is generally not designed to uploading data and the upload bandwidth is in some cases only 10% or less of its download bandwidth. An attacker sending connection requests at only 1Mbps may not hurt its performance, but if you answer them all with another 1Mbps of responses, there goes your server!

Comment: @Havenard *"Linux limits the rate of ICMP error packets to each destination."* - [man 7 icmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html). Not sending ICMP responses will heavily impair your ability to debug connection problems. It pretty surely will not do much in terms of DDoS protection, except in cases of obvious misconfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could possibly cause this pattern of closed ports?

A crappy scanner. You are adding a

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT
```

rule which would result in your host responding with `ICMP type 3 / code 3` message (*destination unreachable - port unreachable*) for all but the previously accepted ports 22, 80 and 443 (the latter not appearing in the scan as well). This should not result in "stealth" ports by any means.

The Gibson [***cannot be trusted***](http://web.archive.org/web/20070521043538/http://grcsucks.com/) and others have made similar observations about the infamous *"Shields Up!"* [***years ago***](http://jml.is/4444/shieldsup-analyzed):

> *GRCs ‘nanoprobes’ diligently connect() to the server and then wander on. The port test, however, tells me my HTTP port is closed. Strange. Very strange. A look at the logs I am sniffing from this connection shows my web server responded - still the test program reports it to be closed. I repeated the exercise with both Windows and Unix based web servers and got an overall hit rate of less than thirty percent, in other words, more than often the test program would not detect my open web server.*

It appears, some things never change.

As an alternative, revert to publicly available, open source tools. [Nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man.html) is a universal scanner you would get with virtually any distribution on a $5/month VPS host. If you only need occasional scans, you could use online nmap services like [***the one from Online Domain Tools***](http://nmap.online-domain-tools.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I normally test with nmap as well which is not showing the closed ports. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: I've had the same results with PF when the `block-policy` is set to RETURN.